# Handle the WPF Close event if WPF application Shut down Forcefully or Crashed

Tags: wpf

I have one server Called GameServer and its continusly run. 
and more then one ClientApplication is running on different different machine.

While user Login to the Server I am saving some  data to server on base of logged in user, and after logout i am doing some changes to the database and also the instance which i made to the server for the logged in user.

But some how if user machine forcefully shut-Down or somethings really bad happent to the  Client Application then user force fully close the client application.

So at that time i want to handel one even in whihc i can call Game Server and do may changes to the Server.

[how to know the application is shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113606/how-to-know-the-application-is-shutting-down)

The above link i see  but it will use for mormally close the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to handle Application_DispatcherUnhandledException when application crashed and CurrentDomain_UnhandledException when Unhandled occured.

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if(ExceptionView != null)
        ExceptionView.ErrorLoger(e.Exception);
   e.Handled = true;
}


void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if(ExceptionView != null)
        ExceptionView.ErrorLoger(ex);
}
```

and at App.XAML use Application_DispatcherUnhandledException handler.

like:- DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"

Comment: What is ExceptionView  ?

Comment: actually ExceptionView  is my Interface Property name, you avoid it. i have put for example only. above both handler you should use in app.XAML.cs.